# React Router throwing <Redirect> outside a <Router> error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using `React-Router 4.3.1` and when i build my webapp i get the error

```
Invariant Violation: "You should not use <Redirect> outside a <Router>"
```

I have used `<Redirect />` in only 3 places and even when i comment them and build I keep getting the same error. Using `serve` on localhost there is no error and it only comes when i use `express` and serve it via an `nginx` proxy.

I have used `<Redirect />` like this

```
<Switch>
    <ProtectedRoute
        path="/dashboard"
        name="Home"
        component={DefaultLayout}
    />
    <ProtectedRoute
        path="/"
        name="Home"
        component={DefaultLayout}
    />
    <Redirect to="/404" />
</Switch>
```

also like this

Where `ProtectedRoute` is

```
  <Route
        path={path}
        {...rest}
        render={props => {
            console.log(getCurrentUser());
            if (!getCurrentUser()) {
                return (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: "/login",
                            state: { from: props.location }
                        }}
                    />
                );
            } else {
                return Component ? <Component {...props} /> : render(props);
            }
        }}
    />
```

and other `<Redirect />` like this

```
<Suspense fallback={this.loading()}>
    <Switch>
        <Redirect from="/" to="/dashboard" />
    </Switch>
</Suspense>
```

The last one as

```
if (getCurrentUser()) return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />;
```

Is there anything wrong with the way i'm using it.

Using `netlify` i can serve without any problems.

Comment: Do you have a Router component wrapping Suspense

Comment: No, Its just ```<Container><Suspense .../></Container>```

Comment: Using `netlify` i can serve without any problems.

Comment: What is meant is that is the Router component in the parent hierarchy of Suspense component otherwise Redirect will be outside of Router which won't work

Comment: Oh, So i need to wrap `<Suspense />` with a Router?